# Find majority element when the values are unknown

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have an array of elements.
I cannot read the values of the elements. I can only compare any two elements from the array to know whether they are the same or not, but even then I don't get to know their actual values.

Suppose this array has a majority of elements of the same value. I need to find and return any of the majority elements. How would I do it?

We have to be be able to do it in a big thet.of n l0g n.

Comment: Can you also show what algorithm you have designed for this case?

Comment: When comparing 2 things can you determine if they are <, >, or == ? Or do you only know if they are equal or not?

Comment: Did you look at the comment / Wikipedia page link which was helpfully left the first time you asked this question? Because it has the algorithm you need.

Comment: 2rici: Would it be possible to use the divide and conquer approach with that algorithm?

Comment: @tmarine: that algorithm is O(n), and you cannot do better than O(n) because you need to look at every element. So there's nothing to conquer. You're already there.

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of two indices, i & j. Initialize i=0, j=1. Repeatedly compare arr[i] to arr[j].

```
if arr[i] == arr[j], increment j.

if arr[i] != arr[j]
  eliminate both from the array
  increment i to the next index that hasn't been eliminated.
  increment j to the next index >i that hasn't been eliminated.
```

The elimination operation will eliminate at least one non-majority element each time it eliminates a majority element, so majority is preserved. When you've gone through the array, all elements not eliminated will be in the majority, and you're guaranteed at least one.

This is O(n) time, but also O(n) space to keep track of eliminations.

Comment: I think this approach works but how do you guarantee that "increment i to the next index that hasn't been eliminated" and "increment j to the next index >i that hasn't been eliminated" takes `O(n)` amortized time? I'm not convinced about that yet.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Both indices can only be incremented n times before you get to the end of the array.

Comment: you don't need two indices, at least not the way you present the algorithm, and you don't need to track eliminations. You only need to track the current candidate while you do a scan. See the Boyer-Moore majority algorithm, wikipedia link in @vincent's answer.

Comment: @rici You can't read values, so you need 2 indices even in the Boyer-Moore version (which is superior). These are 'result' and 'i' as presented by Vincent.

Comment: @dave: true, it's still a two-finger algorithm. I could have phrased that better, but I think you got the essence :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Given:**

- an implicit array `a` of length `n`, which is known to have a majority element
- an oracle function `f`, such that `f(i, j) = a[i] == a[j]`

**Asked:**

Return an index `i`, such that `a[i]` is a majority element of `a`.

**Main observation:**

If

- `m` is a majority element of `a`, and
- for some even `k < n` each element of `a[0, k)` occurs at most `k / 2` times

then `m` is a majority element of `a[k, n)`.

We can use that observation by assuming that the first element is the majority element. We move through the array until we reach a point where that element occurred exactly half the time. Then we discard the prefix and continue again from that point on. This is exactly what the [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm) algorithm does, as pointed out by Rici in the comments.

In code:

```
result = 0  // index where the majority element is
count = 0   // the number of times we've seen that element in the current prefix
for i = 0; i < n; i++ {
  // we've seen the current majority candidate exactly half of the time:
  // discard the current prefix and start over
  if (count == 0) {
    result = i
  }
  
  // keep track of how many times we've seen the current majority candidate in the prefix
  if (f(result, i)) {
    count++
  } else {
    count-- 
  }
}

return result
```

---

For completeness: this algorithm uses two variables and a single loop, so it runs in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

Comment: Would divide and conquer approach work with this algorithm?
If so, what would be the big theta?

Comment: I don't see why you would want to use divide and conquer with this algorithm. It makes a single pass through the data which is clearly as good as it gets. I'm sure you can solve the problem with divide and conquer as well but it would be a completely different algorithm.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you can determine if elements are `<`, `>`, or `==` what you can do is go through the list and build a tree. The trees values will be like buckets, the item and count of how many you've seen. When you come by a node where you get `==` then just increment the count. Then at the end go through the tree and find the one with the highest count.

Assuming you build a balanced tree, this should be O(n log n). Red Black trees might help with making a balanced tree. Else you could build the tree by adding randomly selected elements and this would give you O(n log n) on average.

Comment: No, we don't know if it's < or >. Only if it's == or !=.

Comment: If there are only a small number d distinct elements, instead of a tree you could just do this as a list that would give you complexity O(n d)